# Create TFS query to filter on backlogs or tasks

Tags: tfs

I'm struggling to create a TFS query to filter on either the parent backlog item or the nested child task but I can't figure out if this is possible.

For example. In the current sprint:

- There is one backlog item assigned to user A. This backlog item has no connected tasks
- There is another backlog item assigned to user B. This backlog item is conneted to a task which is assigned to user A.

Is there a way to create a query which returns both of the backlog items above when filtering on current sprint and user A?

Comment: Please post what did you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query like this:
[image]
This will return all the work items assigned to User A and the connected workitems.